# Problems with Forms => Variables are not accepted in the form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Not sure where the problem is in the following form used in a template file in Drupal7. Help is highly appreciated. The problems are the following:
1. The variables $title and $surname are not passed over to the form's default value.
   => Error Message: Notice: Undefined variable: title in form_user_information()
   => Error Message: Notice: Undefined variable: surname in form_user_information()
2. There's a Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in drupal_strip_dangerous_protocols()
Thanks in advance.

```
   <?php
        //Load User data:
            global $user;
            $uid = $user->uid;
            $account = user_load($uid); 

        //Get User data:
            $title = 'Mrs.';
                print $title . '<br><br>'; //Result: Value is printed and not empty!        
            $surname = check_plain($account->field_vorname['und']['0']['value']);
            //$surname = 'Tom';
                print $surname . '<br><br>'; //Result: Both values are printed and are not empty!



        function form_user_information($form, &$form_state) {


        //Form
            $form['#action'][] = request_uri();
            $form['#id'][] = 'form_user_information';
            $form['#validate'][] = 'form_user_information_validators';
            $form['#submit'][] = 'form_user_information_submit';
            $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="form_user_information">';
            $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

            //Select-Field: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#select
            $form['Title'] = array(
                '#type' => 'select',
                '#title' => t('Title'),
                '#options' => array(
                  'Frau' => t('Mr.'),
                  'Herr' => t('Mrs.'),
                ),
                '#default_value' => $title,
            );  

            $form['surname'] = array(
                '#type' => 'textfield',
                '#maxlength' => 50,
                '#size' => 40,
                '#required' => TRUE,
                '#title' => t('Surname'),
                //'#attributes' => array('placeholder' => $surname),
                '#default_value' => $surname,
            );

            $form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
            $form['actions']['submit'] = array('#type' => 'submit', '#value' => 'Confirm data');

        return $form;
        }


        //print form
            $form = drupal_get_form('form_user_information');
            print drupal_render($form);

        //Form Validation:
        function form_user_information_validators($form, &$form_state) {
          if ($form_state['values']['surname'] == '') {
            form_set_error('surname', t('Please enter your surname.'));
          }
        }

        //Form Submit:
        function form_user_information_submit($form, &$form_state) {

            //...

        }

    //get form information
        echo "<pre>".print_r($form,true)."</pre>";  

    ?>
```

Comment: - Putting the variables inside the function works but I don't quite understand why, to be frank.
- $title was just used for the translation for this forum.
- There was an error in my code.
 Correction:
  'Frau' => t('Mr.'),  must be 'Mr.' => t('Mr.') /
  'Herr' => t('Mrs.'), must be 'Mrs.' => t('Mrs.'),
  to make the default value work in the select list.
  
- the error in 2) appears when site is being reloaded. (array given in drupal_strip_dangerous_protocols() (line 1350 of ...includes\common.inc).
Seems that this is the only lasting problem. Thanks for your help so far, Theodoros

Comment: The warning/error in 2. happens because of the following line:       $form['#action'][] = request_uri(); => use $form['#action'] = request_uri(); instead; same probably for $form['#id'][] = 'form_user_information';

Answer (score 0):

1) Set the global variables $title and $surname with global scope:

```
//Get User data:  
$global $title = ...  
$global $surname = ...
```

Otherwise set all these variables (including $user) inside the `function form_user_information` which is the best practice.

I would also suggest not use $title as variable name because it may cause problems with already defined $title of the $page variable. Instead use something like $user_title.

2) Which line does this come from?

Comment: @NickDilis Did this answer solve your problem? If so please give some feedback (upvote, select as acceptable) so the issue is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Guess this issue can be closed. See the 2 comments. Thanks Theodoros for your help.